# Creating highchart linechart with data using PHP (and Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel-4, highcharts

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
month_name | intake_total | adoption_totals
January | 12 | 36
February | 4 | 12
March | 23 | 46
April | 45 | 89
May | 10 | 15
June | 15 | 20
July | 23 | 22
August | 23 | 45
September | 45 | 67
October  | 23 | 12
November | 45 | 100
December | 0 | 12
```

And I am trying to create an array to show a line chart

I have:

```
$chartArray["chart"] = array("type" => "line");
$chartArray["title"] = array("text" => "Intakes vs. Adoptions");
$chartArray["credits"] = array("enabled" => false);
$chartArray["xAxis"] = array("categories" => array());
foreach ($results as $result)
{
$categoryArray[] = $result->month_name;
$chartArray["series"][] = array("name" => 'Intake Totals', "data" => array($result->intake_total));
$chartArray["series"][] = array("name" => 'Adoption Totals', "data" => array($result->adoption_total));
}
$chartArray["xAxis"] = array("categories" => $categoryArray);
$chartArray["yAxis"] = array("title" => array("text" => "Number of Pets"));
return $chartArray;
```

I know that I need to populate the data for each series with all the rows of each type but I can't figure out how to do that. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Maybe this will help someone else:

```
$chartArray["chart"] = array("type" => "line");
        $chartArray["title"] = array("text" => "Intakes vs. Adoptions");
        $chartArray["credits"] = array("enabled" => false);
        $chartArray["xAxis"] = array("categories" => array());
        foreach ($results as $result)
        {
            $categoryArray[] = $result->month_name;

        }

        $intaketotal = [];
        $adoptiontotal = [];
        foreach($results as $result){
            array_push($intaketotal, $result->intake_total);
            array_push($adoptiontotal, $result->adoption_total);
        }

        $chartArray["series"][] = array("name" => 'Intake Totals', "data" =>$intaketotal);
        $chartArray["series"][] = array("name" => 'Adoption Totals', "data" => $adoptiontotal);

        $chartArray["xAxis"] = array("categories" => $categoryArray);
        $chartArray["yAxis"] = array("title" => array("text" => "Number of Pets"));

        return $chartArray;
```